# CURL localhost via online server

Tags: php, curl, localhost

I have a local website setup via MAMP at: `http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/`

Is it possible to CURL this local site via my online site? For example, in `https://example.com/file.php`, I test:

```
$url ='http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($content);
```

But it doesn't work. Is it even possible for the client (website visitor) to access their localhost like this?

Comment: You would need to use the public ip address of your (home?) network and configure your router to forward http traffic to your computer. You might need to configure OSX as well to accept incoming requests on port 80.

Comment: Not directly no. You will need to have a static IP and have your machine run 24/7 and basically be your own web host. Or use a service like ngrok to expose your local machine without having a static ip

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of good free service that let you do the same. Ideal for showing something quickly for testing purpose :-

- http://localtunnel.me/
- https://ngrok.com/
- http://localhost.run/

Answer (score 0):

You can use tool like ngrok for get a live url for your local projects. Please keep in mind that you cannot use ngrok like continues service. its just for quickie local to live platform for like testing purpose

Download ngrok from [here](https://ngrok.com/download) , place the downloaded file in your project folder and simply run ./ngrok http 80

( here 80 is the port assuming your project running. it is subject to change as per your required)